# Connecting to Meteor server using DDP client on local machine

Tags: android, meteor, ddp

I'm trying to connect to the Meteor server that's currently running on my dev machine [using this DDP client](https://github.com/delight-im/Android-DDP). It's running on localhost:3000, and I've done this:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    MeteorSingleton.setLoggingEnabled(true);
    MeteorSingleton.createInstance(this, "ws://10.0.2.2:3000/websocket");
    MeteorSingleton.getInstance().setCallback(this);
}

private void login(String email, String password) {
    Log.i("isConnected()", String.valueOf(MeteorSingleton.getInstance().isConnected()));
    MeteorSingleton.getInstance().loginWithEmail(email, password, new ResultListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String s) {
            Log.i("onSuccess()", s);
            finish();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(String s, String s1, String s2) {
            Log.e("onError()", s + " -> " + s1 + " -> " + s2);
        }
    });
}
```

but for some reason, it keeps giving me this error:

```
I/System.out﹕ payload == {"msg":"result","id":"025c01ef-5052-41a2-807d-1500461c7965","error":{"error":403,"reason":"error.accounts.Login forbidden","message":"error.accounts.Login forbidden [403]","errorType":"Meteor.Error"}}
```

I thought it was a port issue so I kept changing around the port of the websocket, but those ports don't even respond/connect, and I'm not sure what to do anymore. Could someone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

The client does connect successfully, but there is another problem. The error message says it all:

```
"reason":"error.accounts.Login forbidden"
```

Obviously, you have to make some changes to your server code, especially the authentication and login code.

But this is merely a Meteor issue, not related to Android.